# React-select options do not update when using react query

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have a React-Select multi-selected options component in which render options by data from an API. The first time I change the input, the API is called, and the options list my data, everything works well. However, when I type the next thing, the API is still called, but the options do not render the data.

- First API call:
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaR3U.png)
- Options render as I expect:
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUBlb.png)
- Second API call, i still getting data from API:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmBsl.png),
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnj53.png)
- But options do not show any thing:
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFJla.png)

Here's my code:

React Query:

```
export const useQueryUserWithExclude = (query: string, exclude: string[] | []) => {
    const { axios } = useAxios()
    const getQueries = async () => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams({ q: query, e: exclude.toString() })
        const res = await axios.get<QueriesType[]>(`${env.BACK_END_URL}/user?${params.toString()}`);
        return res.data
    };
    const execute = useQuery({ queryKey: query ? ["get-queries-exclude", query] : ["get-queries-exclude"], queryFn: getQueries, enabled: Boolean(query) })
    return { ...execute }
}
```

React Select:

```
const FormatOptionLabel: React.FunctionComponent<OptionLabelType> = ({ userId, email, fullName, request }) => {
    return (
        <div className='flex gap-4 '>
            <div>{email}</div>
            <div >
                {fullName}
            </div>
            {request && request.length > 0 && <div>
                {request[0]?.status}
            </div>}
        </div>
    )
};
const MultiValueContainer = (props: MultiValueGenericProps<OptionLabelType>) => {
    return (
        <div >
            <components.MultiValueContainer {...props} >
                {props.data.email}
            </components.MultiValueContainer>
        </div>
    );
};
export default function NewChat() {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState<string>("");
    const [inputText, setInpuText] = React.useState("");
    const [excludes, setExclude] = React.useState<string[] | []>([])
    const { data } = useQueryUserWithExclude(searchText, excludes)
    const setSearchTextDebounced = React.useRef(
        debounce((searchText: string) => setSearchText(searchText), 300)
    );
    const handleInputChange = (inputText: string, event: InputActionMeta) => {
        if (event.action !== "input-blur" && event.action !== "menu-close") {
            setInpuText(inputText);
            setSearchTextDebounced.current(inputText);
        }
    };
    const noOptionsMessage = () => {
        return 'User not found'
    }
    return (
        <div className='w-[75%] h-full items-center justify-center flex-col'>
            <div className='w-full h-[12%] px-20 flex items-center gap-4 '>
                <div>To:</div>
                <div className='w-full relative'>
                    <Select
                        noOptionsMessage={noOptionsMessage}
                        placeholder={"Add user"}
                        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                        className='z-99 pb-1 '
                        isMulti
                        components={{ MultiValueContainer }}
                        isSearchable
                        options={data}
                        formatOptionLabel={FormatOptionLabel}
                        filterOption={null}
                        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                        inputValue={inputText}
                    />
                </div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```